# How to disable AutoTest in GogLand?

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, goland

I'm writing Go with TDD using GogLand and somehow accidently enable AutoTest feature. After writing the code for a few seconds, the test run automatically which distract me a lot. After searching on the Internet I could not find the solution yet.

What I can adjust at the moment is "Set AutoTest Delay" to 10 seconds but I want to disable completely and run manually. Is there any way and how to do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Toggle auto-test` button is placed on `Run` tool window right under `Rerun Failed Tests` action. Disabling it disables auto-testing completely.

[image: Toggle auto-test]

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for. Thank you. :)